# Why is $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]$ a principal ideal domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I used that $\mathbb{Z}_2[X]$ is a principal ideal domain to understand something but than I realized that in the lecture, we only noted that if we have a field, its polynomial ring is a domain. How do I see that it is a principal ideal domain?

Comment: If $k$ is a field $k[X]$ is an Euclidean domain (hence a fortiori a PID) since given two polynomials $f,g$ we can always find $q,r$ such that $f=gq+r$ and $\deg r<\deg g$ or $r=0$.

Comment: Ah, nice! (15 chars)

Comment: In fact, given any ring $A$ and polynomials $f=a_nx^n+\cdots$ and $g=b_kx^k+\cdots$ we can write $b_k^Nf =gq+r$ for appropriate $N,q,r$. If $b_k$ is invertible, we can always obtain a bonafide division. In particular, we can always divide by monic polynomials in any ring, which is nice.

Answer (score 1):

2 is a prime number so the ring $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is actually a field.